# Py2exe lxml woes

Tags: python, wxpython, lxml, py2exe

I have a wxpython application that depends on lxml and works well when running it through the python interpreter. However, when creating an exe with py2exe, I got this error

```
ImportError: No module named _elementpath
```

I then used `python setup.py py2exe -p lxml`  and I did not get the above error but
another one saying

```
ImportError: No module named gzip
```

Could anyone let me know what the problem is and how I can fix it. Also should I put any
dll files like libxml2, libxslt etc in my dist folder? I searched the computer
and did not find these files, so maybe they aren't needed?

Thanks.

Edit: I just tried with `python setup.py py2exe -p -i gzip` and the exe was created. But the exe generated does not run. I double click it and it doesn't do anything.

Here's the setup.py script i'm using

```
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

setup( windows=[{"script": "gui.py"}] )
```

Edit2: I tried using cx_freeze as an alternative , but got the same

```
ImportError: No module named _elementpath
```

error. Didn't know how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Py2exe allows you to specify additional packages/modules to include with the `options` argument to `setup()`, in case they are not automatically detected. The following should work:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'gui.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
        }
    }
)
```

I've also recently discovered [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which has built-in support for a number of well-known packages, including lxml, so that might be worth a try as well.

Comment: If you want to create it as a **single executable** (without additional pyc, dll, etc.), you can have it as follow: `from distutils.core import setup;
import py2exe, sys;

sys.argv.append('py2exe');
        
setup(
 windows=[{'script': 'your_script.py'}],
 zipfile = None,
 options={
  'py2exe': 
  {
   'bundle_files': 1, 
   'compressed': True,
   'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
  }
 }
);`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will need to do another action more after modify the `setup.py` file.

As described [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs),
it should be necessary to uninstall the package if it is installed on "eggs" archive.
Then install it again by forcing easy_install to dezip the archive with the "-Z" option as following (I had the issue with paramiko package):

```
pip uninstall paramiko
easy_install -Z paramiko
```