# Why am I getting this ImportError?

Tags: python, lxml, py2exe, importerror, lxml.html

I have a `tkinter` app that I am compiling to an `.exe` via `py2exe`.

In the setup file, I have set it to include `lxml`, `urllib`, `lxml.html`, `ast`, and `math`.

When I run `python setup.py py2exe` in a CMD console, it compiles fine. I then go to the `dist` folder It has created, and run the `.exe` file.

When I run the `.exe` I get this popup window.[image: this]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/02fc6000c94c165a696d5072738c676d.png))</sub>

I then procede to open the `Trader.exe.log` file, and the the contents say the following;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Trader.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml\html\__init__.pyc", line 42, in <module>
  File "lxml\etree.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "lxml\etree.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 84, in init lxml.etree (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:190292)
ImportError: cannot import name _elementpath
```

Included [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/58m00rene91z3kf/setup.py) is a copy of my `setup.py` file.

Please help me find the problem here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate I think you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308760/py2exe-lxml-woes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Py2exe lxml woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308760/py2exe-lxml-woes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `py2exe` doesn't realize it should include the `lxml._elementpath` module, which is conditionally imported by `lxml.etree`. You can tell it to include that module explicitly with the `includes` keyword argument in your `setup.py`.

```
setup(
    options={'py2exe': {"includes": ["lxml._elementpath"]}}
)
```

Comment: Add the `lxml._elementpath` module. You can find more information on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308760/py2exe-lxml-woes Try and use a `setup.py` similar to the answer of that question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Py2exe has made documentation of this error on this page: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules

They also offer a working solution.