# from . import _methods ImportError: cannot import name '_methods' in cx-freeze python

Tags: python, python-3.4, cx-freeze

`exe` build successfully by using cx-freeze. But it shows the following error when I execute the `exe` file:

> from . import _methods ImportError: cannot import name '_methods'

Answer (score 27):

This question was already answer here: [Why am I getting this ImportError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133313/why-am-i-getting-this-importerror)
but for the sake of completeness here is the answer for this specific case: cx_freeze is not importing the optional module *_method*, so you have to tell him explicitly to do it.

```
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
setup(name='xyz', 
      version='0.4', 
      description='xyz script',
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': additional_mods}},
      executables = [Executable('xyz.py')]
    )
```

In the code above I have to import also *format*, after *_methods*. For me the 2 modules where enough, may be you need more.

Comment: Thanks Rodolfo! Minor typo: additional_mods (not `addtional_mods`) :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think we are in the same boat. i get the idea from the last post, but i'm not so familiar with the grammar and there is some different grammar with the last post in setup.py.

But I get another way to solve this:

add `import numpy.core._methods` and `import numpy.lib.format` in your python file.

Comment: This is a quick solution that doesn't require setup.py