# Python script works in the IDE but not when built into executable?

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, cx-freeze

When I run my code in Pycharm it parses my Excel files and merges everything correctly in the IDE. However I build it into an executable using [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it stops working. When I double click the executable it doesn't anything. A black console window flashes quickly. What gives. There is no stack trace or error in Pycharm.

Here is my code for reference:

```
[In:]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

 #finds the path to a users pc.
userHome = os.path.expanduser('~')
directory = userHome + '/Desktop/Parsing Script/ParsingScriptOutputFile/'
workerList= (directory+'employeeList.csv')
managerList = (userHome+'/Parsing Script/ParsingScriptOutputFile/managerList.XLSX')

 # specify 32 columns, no headers
employee = pd.read_csv(workerList, usecols=range(32), header=None,  sep=",",engine='python') # read in the data
original_rows = employee.shape[0] # original number of rows
managers = pd.read_excel(managerList)
managers= managers[['Cost Center','Profit Center','User ID', 'Description','Email address','Person Responsible']]

# Left join so that the rows that do not match are not dropped from employee
# data
merged_df = pd.merge(employee, managers, on='key', how='left')

# Number of rows should be unchanged
# This should print out True
print(merged_df.shape[0] == original_rows)
#File called merged_data.csv returned to ParsingScriptOutputFile
return merged_df.to_csv(directory+'merged_data.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8') # Save
```

@ sideffect0 (thanks for the advice) 
Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>

    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line      24, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "csvProject1.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import numeric
   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1842, in <module>
    from .arrayprint import array2string, get_printoptions, set_printoptions
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 24, in <module>
from .fromnumeric import ravel
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _methods
ImportError: cannot import name '_methods'
```

Comment: are the file paths the same? asking because you could be attempting the `exe` on another machine?

Comment: what happens if you run the `exe` from the command line?

Comment: I think you are in windows, open command prompt ( Win + R -> cmd),
run the program from there, you will get traceback with details, then add the traceback in this question

Comment: File paths are the same,
@asongtoruin Same thing, 
Yes this is a method part of a larger parsing script. However I have taken this method out of the larger script and the rest of thescript runs fine. I tried building only this code using cx_Freeze and it won't work. And it still works in pycharm.

Comment: @sideeffect0 thanks for the tip.

Comment: may help [from . import _methods ImportError: cannot import name '_methods' in cx-freeze python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735413/from-import-methods-importerror-cannot-import-name-methods-in-cx-freeze-p)

Comment: @downshift. Thanks for that link. Your fix worked! I think it was a error with a module not installing correctly. Coupled with a corrupted numpy installation.

Comment: That's great news @greenbai, I'm really glad to hear you fixed it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a module not correctly installing In the setup.py file I used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735413/from-import-methods-importerror-cannot-import-name-methods-in-cx-freeze-p) from this stackoverflow answer that @downshift linked me. Also I found that I had a corrupted installation of numpy. So I did a quick uninstall and re-install of that. Rebuilt the script into an executable and it worked perfectly.

To get the full traceback I navigated to the executable in the command line and typed in the filename. A quicker way of doing this is hold down `alt`and right clicking on the file that contains your exe, then click open `open command window` this will open cmd at the file location for you. Run your program for there to get the traceback