# Error using cx_freeze with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scikit-learn, cx-freeze, gdal

I prepared the script for a GUI using Tkinter that is working well when I run it as a script. But I wish to share my application to others who don't have Python installed on their computer. The 'python setup.py build' is running without error and creates the required directories and files', but gives lot of errors when I run the .exe file.

The packages that I'm importing in the script are:

```
#gdal
#Tkinter
#cv2
#sklearn
```

I'm using a Windows 7 professional Service Pack 1, 32-bit machine.

```
#Python version : 3.5.5
#cx_Freeze version: 4.3.3
```

Please check the error screen-shot below:
[image]

Comment: There is no error screenshot.

Comment: You show that you are importing `Tkinter` but you're using python 3. Python 3 renamed `Tkinter` to `tkinter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735413/from-import-methods-importerror-cannot-import-name-methods-in-cx-freeze-p

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure without your actual setup script but it looks like you just need to add `numpy` and `numpy._methods` to your  packages list.

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy", "numpy._methods"]}
```