# pyinstaller: ImportError: cannot import name _elementpath

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-docx

I'm using the command : pyinstaller -w -F main.py

And I got this message when I tried to run the exe file:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 1, in <module> 
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "ms_word.py", line 2, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx_*init*_.py", line 3, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx\api.py", line 14, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx\package.py", line 9, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx\opc\package.py", line 9, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx\opc\part.py", line 12, in <module>
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
> File "docx\opc\oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
> File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 74, in init lxml.etree
> ImportError: cannot import name _elementpath

It seems it is related with *docx* import, since this error doesn't appear when I disabled *docx* from my code.

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps similar to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133313/why-am-i-getting-this-importerror

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem when using Pycharm with Python 3.8.10. I tried to solve it but no solution found. However, the same program when used with system interpreter version 3.9.6 and packed with `pyinstaller` on system cmd produced no errors. In general, it seems when packed in Pycharm it produces many errors (even when the user's Python versions are the same as the system's Python version).

Before encountering this error, I got stuck in the `pythoncom module isn't in frozen sys.path` error.

Just add `--hidden-import lxml._elementpath` in `pyinstaller ...` line.